# Enzyme: How to test interactions on shallow component

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

[image]

### I want to test some basic UI interaction with my list component.

I want to test, that a given 'select all' checkbox works, using Enzyme+Jest with a shallow root object.

Beforehand, I verify, nothing is selected. That does work nicely:

```
const allBox = list.find('Checkbox.select-all')
expect(allBox.prop('checked')).toBe(false)
mainRows.find('Checkbox').forEach( (node) => {
    expect(node.prop('checked')).toBe(false)
})
```

**But I can't trigger a 'click' (or 'change') on that master checkbox…**

```
allBox.simulate('click')`
```

I suspect, because Checkbox is still a shallow `<Checkbox>` not an actual html-ish `<input type='checkbox'…>`.

### But what can I do?

Mounting (actually rendering) the entire list component will become to vast. Can I somehow just mount the (rather tiny) Checkbox subcomponent, to then trigger its events? And/or do I need to [.dive()](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html)?

### Anything else before `expect()`ing that all is selected now?

The `checked`-properties of the various `<Checkbox>` are tied to component state. So do I need to `list.instance().update()`? Or even `.forceUpdate()`? → There is [some discussion on the Enzyme tracker](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1229#issuecomment-344077724), on wether/how .update() works…

Anyway, **no luck for me**:

```
Expected value to be:       true
Received:                   false

  180 |         allBox.simulate('change')
  181 |         list.instance().forceUpdate()
  182 | 
> 183 |         expect(allBox.prop('checked')).toBe(true)
  184 |         // verify, that did the job:
  185 |         mainRows.find('Checkbox').forEach( (node) => {
  186 |             expect(node.prop('checked')).toBe(true)
```

Comment: This works for me: query that selector again after the `simulate` call. like this:
`expect(list.find('.select-all').prop('checked')).toBe(true)`.

Comment: could you share the code for the component that you're shallow rendering? Does it manage the state for the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

#### 'change', not 'click'

Well, first of all, I have to simulate 'change', not 'click'. Since the `<Checkbox>` component in all its shallowness only has an on**Change**-handler. (that click would lead to change is only true, if it turned into actual html… sinca that is, what `<input type="checkbox…>` does)

---

### Now to the core issue:

> list.find('.list-bottombar').find('Checkbox.select-all').debug()

```
<Checkbox className="select-all" checked={false}…
```

Let's trigger the change:

> list.find('.list-bottombar').find('Checkbox.select-all').simulate('change')

Did we do well?

> list.find('.list-bottombar').find('Checkbox.select-all').debug()

**Yes!**

```
<Checkbox className="select-all" checked={true}…
```

Would using the shorthand show the same thing?

> bottomBar.find('Checkbox.select-all').debug()

```
<Checkbox className="select-all" checked={false}…
```

**NO!** So @konekoya is right, you have to keep retrieving by find, no prior shorthands allowed. (Hmm. Ha. Is that anywhere in the docs?!?)

---

### Would a [force]update help?  (Spoiler: No.)

> bottomBar.update()

```
Error: ShallowWrapper::update() can only be called on the root
```

Fine, then

> list.update()
>   bottomBar.find('Checkbox.select-all').debug()

```
<Checkbox className="select-all" checked={false}…
```

No luck.

> list.instance().update()
>   TypeError: list.instance(...).update is not a function
>   list.instance().forceUpdate()
>   bottomBar.find('Checkbox.select-all').debug()

```
<Checkbox className="select-all" checked={false}…
```

(although the box is still checked, as above long query still verifies)

Dive is not helping either.

#### tl;dr; Any shortcut to the old list is simply a shortcut to obsolete data. One has to `find()` from root element time and again.

---

P.S. someone in the know from Enzyme [quite explicitly confirms this](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1221#issuecomment-334974967)

> when you use .find in v2, you get a wrapper that updates automatically
>   when the root wrapper updates. In v3, it's immutable, so you have to
>   re-find from the root to see changes reflected.